# Displaying specific data from a CSV/JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv, papaparse

I want to display specific fields from an external CSV file on a web site with using JavaScript.
I tried to parse that file with using "Papa parse" like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Parse remote CSV to HTML Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.0/mustache.min.js'></script>
 
 <script>
 Papa.parse("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/....../data.csv?dl=0", {
 download: true,
 header: true,
 complete: function(results) {
 console.log(results);
 }
});
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this give me the result in console:

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuqNg.jpg)

My question is;
How can I display a specific data from this data set in a web site like:

**Battery Level:** 0.62

**Altimeter Pressure:** 99.44185

**Horizontal Accuracy:** 65

etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Battery Level as an example (the other fields are similar and you should be able to figure it out youself):

```
var data = results.data
var arrayLength = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'your_div_id_'+i.toString());

    newdiv.innerHTML = 'Battery Level: '+data[i].batteryLevel.toString();
}
```

Comment: I created a jsbin. http://jsbin.com/weqiviguci/1/edit?html,js,console,output .I am getting "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" error.